# Windows Serial Port Not Connecting Properly?

Tags: c++, windows, arduino, serial-port

I have a code to communicate with an Arduino Uno. It is C++, and it is run from a GUI. I wrote a class for serial communication, to be used within the GUI. My guess is the Serial Port is an issue as it is what throws the error.
The class code is:

```
#ifndef SERIALPORTV2_H
#define SERIALPORTV2_H
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class SerialPortV2
{
    public:
        SerialPortV2(std::string comPort, std::string baudRate)
        {
            open(comPort, baudRate);
        }

        SerialPortV2()
        {
            printf("New serial port created");
        }

        ~SerialPortV2()
        {
            close();
        }

        void open(std::string comx, std::string baud)
        {
            hComm = CreateFile(comx.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                std::cout<<"Error in opening serial port"<<std::endl;
                opened = false;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"opening serial port successful"<<std::endl;
                opened = true;
                DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 }; // Initializing DCB structure
                dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
                GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
                dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
                dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;         // Setting ByteSize = 8
                dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;// Setting StopBits = 1
                dcbSerialParams.Parity   = NOPARITY;  // Setting Parity = None
                SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
            }
        }

        void close()
        {
            CloseHandle(hComm);
            opened = false;
        }

        bool isOpen()
        {
            return opened;
        }

        std::string readSerialPort()
        {
            std::string buff;
            char temp;
            DWORD bytesRead;
            std::cout<<"Reading from arduino..."<<std::endl;
            do
            {
                ReadFile(hComm, &temp, sizeof(temp), &bytesRead, NULL);
                std::cout<<"From serial reader: "<<temp<<std::endl;
                buff += temp;
            }
            while(bytesRead > 0);
            std::cout<<"Reading from arduino done"<<std::endl;
            buff.pop_back();
            return buff;
        }
        void writeSerialPort(std::string msg)
        {
            char buff[64];
            strcpy(buff, msg.c_str());
            DWORD dNoOFBytestoWrite;
            DWORD dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;
            dNoOFBytestoWrite = sizeof(buff);
            std::cout<<"TEST: "<<buff<<std::endl;
            WriteFile(hComm, buff, dNoOFBytestoWrite, &dNoOfBytesWritten, NULL);
        }

    private:
        HANDLE hComm;
        bool opened;

    protected:


};
#endif // SERIALPORTV2_H
```

When I compile my program with this class the following error is thrown:

```
C:\Users\matthew\Desktop\PersonalHeaders\SerialPortV2.h|29|error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'void* CreateFileW(LPCWSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, DWORD, DWORD, HANDLE)'|
```

So I change it to be LPCWSTR (I use all the right conversions and such) but then it throws the opposite, "Cannot convert LPCWSTR to LPCSTR"

My fix is to use CreateFileA or CreateFileW, with the proper variable conversions. these work in terms of compiling.

When I run the code (With the compiling versions (CreateFileA or CreateFileW))and select the COM port the Arduino is on (COM6), it will reset the Arduino, but nothing is sent via RX or TX (as seen from Arduino LEDs)

Then I can open the Arduino Serial Monitor no problem and communicate without a hitch to the Arduino. When I try to reconnect with my GUI, the console says the COM port failed to open.

I have no idea why as it was working fine, then without me changing anything, it stopped working and I have been perplexed ever since.

Comment: 1. Check the return values of every Windows function. 2. Use a debugger.

Comment: @ZDF I use the default in Code::Blocks, the GDB Dubgger. How can I check return values when they're already being checked.

Comment: i.e. `if ( !GetCommState(...) ) cout << GetLastError();`. See [GetCommState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommstate). Since you are working in Windows I would use Visual Studio Community - it is free and it has a great debugger.

Comment: I have finally managed to test your class; for writing, only. It works (kind of: it writes too many bytes). It must be something specific to your system. I have used Visual Studio.

Comment: @ZDF If there is no error thrown in the first place, and when opened, CommState is essentially open, then how can there be an error to be caught? I also prefer to not use Visual Studio. i don't like making non-easily ported code (Serial Ports are easy to do for other OSs, it's just window thats a pain)

Comment: @ZDF Also, my code doesn't work on my two computers.

Comment: Maybe the port is kept open by other application. Did you close the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Or you try to open it twice, at the same time, from your application.

Comment: @ZDF Arduino IDE was closed when I tried it. I moved on from trying to use this code and instead created a wrapper class to use asio::serial_port without changing massive amounts of my pre-made code. I really appreciate the help, however, thank you.